# Validation loss decreasing when turning on dropout

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I built a nn with tensorflow. I used dropout to regularize it. After training I tested it on a validation set and got an accuracy of 0.37. Then just for testing purposes I turned on dropout again and my validation accuracy increased to 0.87.
How is this possible. Using dropout should make the model worse.
Here is my code defining the nn architecture:

```
with tf.name_scope('train_data'):
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 28, 28, 1))
    Y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(None, 36))

train = tf.placeholder_with_default(False, shape=())
batch_size = tf.placeholder_with_default(1, shape=())

def layer(inp, k, l, train, padding='SAME'):
    with tf.name_scope('layer'):
        z = tf.layers.conv2d(inp, k, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding=padding, kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.he_normal(), name='z'+l)
        bn = tf.layers.batch_normalization(z, epsilon=1e-7, name='bn'+l)
        a = tf.nn.leaky_relu(bn, 0.2)
        d = tf.layers.dropout(a, rate=0.5, training=train, name='d'+l)
        return (z, bn, a, d)    

with tf.name_scope('network'):
    d0 = tf.layers.dropout(X, rate=0.2, training=train, name='d0')
    z1, bn1, a1, d1 = layer(d0, 32, '1', train)
    p1 = tf.nn.max_pool(d1, ksize=(1, 2, 2, 1), strides=(1, 2, 2, 1), padding='VALID', name='p1')
    z2, bn2, a2, d2 = layer(p1, 64, '2', train)
    p2 = tf.nn.max_pool(d2, ksize=(1, 2, 2, 1), strides=(1, 2, 2, 1), padding='VALID', name='p2')
    fc2 = tf.layers.flatten(p2, name='fc2')
    enc = tf.layers.dense(fc2, 36, name='fc3')

with tf.name_scope('encodings'):
    target = tf.slice(enc, [0, 0], [batch_size, -1])
    for i in range(36):
        globals()['enc'+str(i)] = tf.slice(enc, [(1+i)*batch_size, 0], [batch_size, -1])

with tf.name_scope('prediction'):
    logits = tf.concat([-tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean((globals()['enc'+str(i)] - target)**2, axis=1, keepdims=True)) for i in range(36)], 1)
    out = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

with tf.name_scope('cost'):
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=Y, logits=logits))
```

Then I trained the model using an ADAM-optimizer and set train to True during training.

```
_, loss, acc = sess.run([trainig_op, cost, accuracy], feed_dict={X: x_batch, Y: y_batch, train: True, batch_size: bs})
```

Finally for evaluation I calculated the acc on my validation set and set the train parameter to False.

```
loss, acc = sess.run([cost, accuracy], feed_dict={X: x_batch, Y: y_batch, batch_size: bs})
```

Comment: Dropout should make the _training_ accuracy worse, in the name of preventing overfitting, therefore improving validation accuracy. Sounds like your model is a poster child for why dropout exists!

Comment: The problem is that the validation accuracy is better when I turn it on while validating

Comment: Could you cite a reference backing your claim that "*Using dropout should make the model much worse*"? As @G.Anderson above, I highly doubt that this is true in general

Comment: You're adding dropout at the input layer. Though you can do that, the dropout rate is higher at 50%. That was done in the original paper. However that's where you're only doing it. Did you apply dropout on the rest of the layers? This is usually done before the activations.

Comment: @desertnaut by using dropout should make the model worse I mean: While you are using dropout the performance of the model should be worse compared to while not using it for the same task

Comment: @desertnaut from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropout_(neural_networks)) "Dropout is a regularization technique patented by Google for reducing overfitting in neural networks by preventing complex co-adaptations on training data." Not sure what else to say except that that's what dropout is for

Comment: I perfectly understood what you mean, and I asked for corroboration to back this "*should*"

Comment: Where exactly do you see in the provided link that the validation performance with dropout should be not only worse, but *much* worse?